# AngularJS performance tracing tools

Tags: performance, angularjs, trace

I'm in the middle of migrating a large system from pure Asp.net Mvc into Asp.net Web Api + AngularJS.

I have 100-500 inputs per page.
 Each input is a directive called 'field' that has multiple directive connected to it.

I would like to get a recommendation on a performance tool that will give me information about the bottle necks(something similar to the Ants Performance Tool that works with .net) or other tips for tracing performance issues(per browser will be great).

Comment: In addition to JavaScript profiling available in most browsers, you can also look at the Chrome extension batarang which offers several AngularJS tools that help with identifying scoping issues and various other issues.

Comment: I know about Batarang - It doesn't have enough features and in addition, it gets stuck when I'm analyzing rich pages of my application.
Thanks anyway!!!